# Google listing results from "stackoverflow.com.exactgo.com"?

Tags: discussion

I recently did a google search which resulted in links to a domain "stackoverflow.com.exactgo.com". If I enter the "Exactgo.com" domain into the browser, reddit.com content is displayed.

I am not sure if this is a phish/fraud or anything similar but I would think that the management of stackexchange might not be too happy about this - provided that the domain does not belong to them.

Here is the google query in question:

https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=netbeans+github+auth+fails&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=20YwVvmgEMP4mAXHsL_4Bw

one of the results point to:

http://stackoverflow.com.exactgo.com/questions/21777996/unable-to-push-to-github-using-netbeans-7-4

If you want to see more results, simply google for "what is exactgo.com", most of the results are similarly redirected stackexchange network pages.